# custom icon in Leaflet not working

Tags: leaflet

The standard method of using a custom icon as shown in the Leaflet docs isn't working for me when I have a geojson data source.  the layer is added fine, but is using the default marker icon.  There's no reference to my custom icon PNG when i examine the DOM.  Here's my code:

```
    var crossIcon = L.icon({
            iconUrl: 'plus.png',
            shadowUrl: 'marker-shadow.png',
            iconSize: [11, 11],
            shadowSize: [11, 11],
            iconAnchor: [6, 6],
            shadowAnchor: [5, 5],
            popupAnchor: [5, 5]
    });


    var points = L.geoJson(labels, {
            icon: crossIcon
    });
    map.addLayer(points);
    layerControl.addOverlay(points, 'Site Locations');
```

I've tried several suggestions found on SO and elsewhere with no success.  plus.png is located in /lib/images/ where the default icon is also found.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Looking at the API for GeoJson [here](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson), there is no such option when creating a L.GeoJson layer for `icon`. I believe you may be looking for the [style option](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson-style), for polylines and polygons, or the [pointToLayer](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson-pointtolayer) option for specifying icons.

The [sample GeoJson page](http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson-example.html) on Leaflet's website shows this scenario. Look at the icon with the baseball player.

The icon is defined in this way:

```
var baseballIcon = L.icon({
        iconUrl: 'baseball-marker.png',
        iconSize: [32, 37],
        iconAnchor: [16, 37],
        popupAnchor: [0, -28]
    });
```

The icon is applied to the `L.geoJson` layer through the `pointToLayer` option, which specifies a function; like this:

```
var coorsLayer = L.geoJson(coorsField, {
        pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
            return L.marker(latlng, {icon: baseballIcon});
        }
    })
```

This function will be called for each GeoJSON point. The function will return an `L.Marker` that uses your specified icon.

**So, to answer your question:** Your code block that creates your Layer should look like this:

```
var points = L.geoJson(labels, {
        pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
            return L.marker(latlng, {icon: crossIcon });
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than adding it as geojson layer you can add it as a marker

```
var crossIcon = L.icon({
        iconUrl: 'plus.png',
        shadowUrl: 'marker-shadow.png',
        iconSize: [11, 11],
        shadowSize: [11, 11],
        iconAnchor: [6, 6],
        shadowAnchor: [5, 5],
        popupAnchor: [5, 5]
});

       L.marker(icon:crossIcon);
```